# Add p-value and/or 95% CI in the text of a correlation matrix / pairs plot

Tags: r, correlation, ggpubr, ggally, ggpairs

Is it possible to add in the text of the correlation matrix plot the exact p-value and/or 95% CI, next to where the point estimate is mentioned, by adding something to this code?

[image]

I welcome solutions using other packages too.

```
 ggpairs(baseline2, title="correlogram ")
```

df

```
baseline2 <- structure(list(delta_bp = c(-21.5, 7, -17.5, -10.5, -21, -7.5, 
4.5, 3, -9, 9, -22.5, -9.5), delta_bp_05 = c(-21.5, 0, 3, -13.5, 
-13, -4, -16.5, -8, 5, -5, -12, 0.5), delta_bp_10 = c(-26.5, 
1, -6, -10.5, -9, -3, -20.5, -10, 1, -6, -22, -0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`17` = 17L, 
`27` = 27L, `32` = 32L), class = "omit"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ggally_statistic` function via the `"statistic"` option to `upper` and supply your own `text_fn`.  The function you give to `text_fn` takes the data columns and should return the text string to display.   Here it is with the p-value and confidence interval added to the correlation.  This can be customised however you like.

```
tf = function(x,y) {
  ct <- cor.test(x, y)
  sprintf("Corr: %0.2f, p: %0.3f\n95%% CI: (%0.2f to %0.2f)", 
          ct$estimate, ct$p.value, ct$conf.int[1], ct$conf.int[2])
}

ggpairs(baseline2, title="correlogram ", 
        upper=list(continuous=wrap("statistic",text_fn=tf,title=NULL, sep=NULL)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to add 95% CI too?

Comment: I've added this and a better way to change the custom text using `ggally_statistic`.  You can customise it now however you want.

Comment: ggpairs(baseline2, title="correlogram ", 
        upper=list(continuous=wrap("statistic",text_fn=tf,title=NULL, sep=NULL))) Using this code, How can i change it to be a spearman corre? I am not being unable of doing it while mantaing this settings. ty

Comment: `cor.test` doesn't return a confidence interval with `method=spearman` so you'd have to find some other way to calculate it